# How to write search query using OR instead of And

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to write search based on following criteria:

I need to find all records that match values of 
key1 **OR** key2 **OR** key 3 values...etc

The number of keys and values is variable

```
 List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> filterlist = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("Key1", new []{"jay","bloggs"}),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("Key2", new []{"joe","blog","doe"}),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("Key3", new []{"jon","blog"}),
        };
```

**Now my implementation**

My current implementation does search but all expressions are "AND" instead of **OR**. I am not sure how to write it.

```
public class UserSearcher
    {
        private List<UserProfile> userProfiles;
        public UserSearcher()
        {
            userProfiles = new List<UserProfile>();
        }

        public static List<UserProfile> SearchProfiles(List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> filterList)
        {
            var list = new List<UserProfile>();
            var query = list.AsQueryable();

            // search for each pair inside as or 
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> searchPair in filterList)
            {
                foreach (string searchString in searchPair.Value)
                {
                    string s = searchString;
                    // search for each item inside as and (has to contains all search strings
                    query = query.Where(x => x.PersonName.Contains(s));
                }
            }
            return list = query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

The full example except db is:
https://gist.github.com/cpoDesign/acf69bc242ed0755597d

Comment: My recent experience with implementing search via EF leads me to believe that handcrafted SQL is the way to go for search for performance reasons.

Comment: @SamAxe that is concern for me too, thnx for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Use [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) - it works well.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I got it right, you want to get back list of `UserProfile` where `PersonName` is inside any `string[]` of `KeyValuePair` list.

If so, try with this:

```
public static List<UserProfile> SearchProfiles(List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> filterList)
{
    var list = new List<UserProfile>();

    return list.Where(profile => filterList.Any(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(profile.PersonName))).ToList();
}
```

Test example:

[image: Test image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> 
      Or<T>(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T,bool>>> expList){
     ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
     Expression r = null;
     foreach(var exp in expList){
        r = r == null ? exp : Expression.Or(r,exp);
     }
     return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(r.Body,pe);
 }



 var orList = new List<Expression<Func<T,bool>>>();
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> searchPair in filterList)
 {
     foreach (string searchString in searchPair.Value)
     {
          string s = searchString;
          // search for each item inside as and 
          // (has to contains all search strings
                orList.Add(x => x.PersonName.Contains(s));
      }
 }

 query = query.Where( Or(expList));
```